# Join three tables without union

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have this table

```
Main_Table

Date    Center      Response    Indicator       IDSurvey
--------------------------------------------------------
11-14   C1          10          LOP             432
11-15   C2          20          IUY             235
11-16   C1          35          LOP             125
11-17   C3          65          OIU             548
11-18   C3          45          OIU             693
11-19   C2          68          RES             236
```

I need to join this table with two mutually exclusive tables

```
Table_A
----------------------------------
Center      Group       Indicator
C1          GroupA1     LOP
C2          GroupA2     IUY
C3          GroupA3     OIU

Table_B
--------------------------------
Center      Group       IDSurvey
C1          GroupB1     236
```

A join with union will bring the six records of my main table. Is there a way to do this without union?

This is the query

```
select da.Date, da.Center, da.Response, da.Indicator, da.IDSurvey 
from Main_Table da
join Table_A ca 
on da.Indicator = ca.Indicator and ca.Center=da.Center
union
select da.Date, da.Center, da.Response, da.Indicator, da.IDSurvey 
from Main_Table da
join Table_B ca 
on ca.Center=da.Center and ca.IDSurvey=da.IDSurvey
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use `union`?

Comment: @Supersnake many reasons, two of them: just curiosity and the aim to get the best solution

Comment: The best solution may well be a `union` query. Perhaps using `union all`.

Comment: As you don't use any of the columns from Table_A or Table_B and apparently you still want to return all the records from Main regardless.  So what role do you think Table_A and Table_B should be playing?  Why not just select all the rows from Main?

Answer (score 4):

Why not just do a `JOIN` with `TableB` as well along with `TableA` like

```
select da.Date, da.Center, da.Response, da.Indicator, da.IDSurvey 
from Main_Table da
left join Table_A ca 
on da.Indicator = ca.Indicator and ca.Center = da.Center
left join Table_B ba 
on ba.Center = da.Center and ba.IDSurvey = da.IDSurvey;
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me, I'm in oracle and this gives me no records; I think the reason is because the join is made with the table_a first and then that result is trying to be joined with table_b

Comment: @NatyBizz, In such case consider doing a `LEFT JOIN` instead. see edit in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are only selecting rows from the main table.  I think you should use `in` or `exists` instead:

```
select da.Date, da.Center, da.Response, da.Indicator, da.IDSurvey 
from Main_Table da
where exists (select 1 from Table_A ca where da.Indicator = ca.Indicator and ca.Center = da.Center) or
      exists (select 1 from Table_B ca where ca.Center = da.Center and ca.IDSurvey = da.IDSurvey)
```

Your `union` is also removing duplicates.  By using `exists` you need neither a `union` nor duplicate elimination.  And, this can make good use of indexes on `Table_A` and `Table_B`.

Answer (score 0):

To get precisely same result as 2 joins with union you need to exclude records from master table without any details with following WHERE clause:

```
select da.Date, da.Center, da.Response, da.Indicator, da.IDSurvey 
from Main_Table da
left join Table_A ca 
on da.Indicator = ca.Indicator and ca.Center = da.Center
left join Table_B ba 
on ba.Center = da.Center and ba.IDSurvey = da.IDSurvey
WHERE (ca.rowid is not null or ba.rowid is not null);
```

Btw, `union` also does `group by` implicitly. So if you really want to remove duplicates then you need to add `group by` all columns as well.